# How to pass a variable value to JINJA {{}} like variable C in {{ result.$C.6 }}?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am running an app in Flask, and I need to fill some portlets in a particular order. Because of that I'm using an auxiliary variable to look for the correct item that I want and can not pass "c value" to statement:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body  %}
<body>
{% set c=0 %}
{% for x in result %}
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <div class="kt-widget24">
        <h4 class="kt-widget24__title">{{ result.$c.1}}</h4>
        <span class="kt-widget24__desc"><h6 font="bold">{{ result.$c.3}}</h6></span>
    </div>
    <span class="kt-widget24__stats kt-font-success"><br><h6>{{ result.$c.6 }}</h6>  </span> 
    {% set c=c+1 %}  
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind Regards,
Carlos

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to pass the variable: using the notation: result[c][1]

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body  %}
<body>
{% set c=0 %}
{% for x in result %}
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <div class="kt-widget24">
        <h4 class="kt-widget24__title">{{ result[c][1]}}</h4>
        <span class="kt-widget24__desc"><h6 font="bold">{{ result[c][3]}}</h6> . 
</span>
    </div>
<span class="kt-widget24__stats kt-font-success"><br><h6>{{result[c][6]}}</h6>  
</span> 
{% set c=c+1 %}  
</div>
</body>
```